# Recargar un div tras petición AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Estoy utilizando Django con AJAX mediante la librería intercooler.js (AJAX automatizado). ¿Hay alguna forma de recargar un div tras realizar una petición AJAX sin tener que recargar la página entera? Si conocéis JSF sería la función update la que me gustaría implementar.

Mi caso en concreto es que tengo el inicio de sesión en un modal y envío el formulario mediante AJAX, me gustaría que tras iniciar sesión se me recargue el header con las opciones tras haber logueado´.

Comment: a que te refieres con recargar div? limpiarlo? borrarlo?

Comment: Actualizarlo. Es decir, si en mi header tengo iniciar sesión y cerrar sesión, tras loguearme en el sistema mediante una petición AJAX, me actualice el header de tal forma que solo me saldría el cerrar sesión. JSF tiene una función llamada update="id del elemento HTML" que te actualiza únicamente ese elemento HTML.

Comment: agrega el codigo de tu header

Comment: y hago eso con todos los divs? jaja además no podría, no puedo devolver divs separados y después estar filtrando a ver dónde coloco cada uno

Comment: agrega tu codigo a tu pregunta Jota....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aquí está la respuesta:

```
$("#divid").load(" #divid");
```

Te refresca únicamente el DOM con el ID que le digas. Obligatorio el espacio después del `load` tal y como aparece.